# Issues with arrays and while loop in python

Tags: django, while-loop, django-queryset

I am fetching the data from raw sql query in django, But I got confused with arrays and while loop in this. Suppose my select query returns 4 rows , 2 rows for one user thus four rows will have the data of 2 users. But the two rows corresponding to one user have similar data expect last column.

```
r1 --> a , b , c , d , 1 
r2 -- > a , b , c , d , 0
```

In php I have done it like this .
$arr=array();

```
while($result= mysql_fetch_assoc($select))
    { 
        if(!isset($arr[$result['entity_id']]['lastname'])){
            $arr[$result['entity_id']]['firstname'] = $result['info'];
        }
        $arr[$result['entity_id']]['lastname'] = $result['info'];
        $arr[$result['entity_id']]["email"]=$result['email'];
        $arr[$result['entity_id']]["style_quiz_score"]=$result['style_quiz_score'];
        $arr[$result['entity_id']]["style_quiz_answer"]=$result['style_quiz_answer'];
        $arr[$result['entity_id']]["date_joined"]=$result['date_joined'];
        $arr[$result['entity_id']]["is_active"]=$result['is_active'];

        $arr[$result['entity_id']]["username"]=normalize_str($result['email']);
    }
```

But I am struck how I can do this in django , How I can use multi-array inside while loop, If I use for loop OR while loop like this :

```
arr={}

    for row in cursor:
      arr[row['0']]['firstname']=row[0]

      **OR**
    while row in cursor:
        pass
```

then it gives errors.

So please suggest me some way how I can do this in django as I did in PHP.

Comment: can some one tell me the alternative of `while($result= mysql_fetch_assoc($select))`   in django. I have tried this `while result is not None:` but it turns into infinite loop

Comment: You should study the django documentation a bit more.

Comment: The cursor part looks a lot like you are using Python's SQL libraries instead of Django's ORM. If that is the case, cursor has a few methods to get the results of the query - `fetchone`, `fetchall`, etc. Perhaps you should take a look at [this tutorial on MySQLdb](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/) if this is your case (you can guess by the `import MySQLdb` part)? If that is not the case, you can post some more code and the errors you recieve.

Answer (score 1):

My way to fetch rows from cursor (using MySQLdb library):

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    variable = row[number_of_column]
```

Some code for check if element exists in multi-array:

```
array = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
for element in array:
    if element[0] == 1:
        print 'ok'
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly?
Try it this way:

```
arr = {}
rows = dictfetchall(cursor)
for row in rows:
    if not arr.get(row['entity_id'], False):
        arr[row['entity_id']] = {}
    ...
```